# Server hardware requirements for SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, hardware

As the title says, i'm trying to figure out how much RAM is needed to generate and export to excel a large report using SQL Server Reporting Services on Windows Server 2003.

It is not an option to upgrade it to SS2008 and also not an option to export to CSV.

Strictly from a hardware point of view what is a good configuration for a high load server?
(CPU's, RAM, Storage)

Comment: Does this large report already exist, or are you trying to prepare for all possibilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got problems - the **maximum** memory size that SSRS2005 can handle is 2GB. (There is a dodge to enable it to handle 3GB, but it's not recommended for production servers.)

SSRS2008 has no such limitation, which is why the normal response in this situation is to recommend an upgrade to 2008.

If your large report won't run on a machine with 2GB available, it doesn't matter how much RAM (or other resources) you put on your server - the report still won't run.

Your only option (given the restrictions stated above) would be to break the report up into smaller pieces and run them one at a time.

Comment: i've found the same solutions while doing some more comprehensive research. the fact of the matter is that the set server is actually a virtual machine that has 4GB of available RAM, with some settings it can be configured to run on all available RAM, but this is a not so pretty solution. Thank you for taking time to respond to my question.

Comment: I hadn't realised that that was the case +1. Can you put in a source for this 2gb limit please?

Comment: It was about a year ago I ran into this issue. I can't find the exact reference for it, but this page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909678 , which is applicable to both SSRS 2000 and SSRS 2005, does refer to the issue - it also mentions that the way to make 3 GB available is to enable the /3GB switch in the Boot.ini file.